# Set a custom function as handler to all signals

Tags: c, unix, signals

I have this assignment to do:

Write a function `void myfunct(void(*f)(int sig))` which sets `f` as handler to all the possible signals.

I have two problems:

1. How can a get all the possible signals? Is there a function for this? Can I iterate through them in some way?
2. Will it really work to set the function `f` as handler given that it takes a parameter? Shouldn't it not have any parameters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How can a get all the possible signals? Is there a function for this? Can I iterate through them in some way?

Most implementation provide a constant such as `NSIG` ([Glibc provides `NSIG`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Signals.html)) or `_NSIG` ([Linux provides _NSIG](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/signal.h#L6)). So, you can loop through that constant and set the same signal handling function for all of them.

There's no POSIX defined value for "highest signal number". There's been a [proposal in POSIX](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=741) to add a macro `NSIG_MAX`.

> {NSIG_MAX}
>
> Maximum possible return value of sysconf(_SC_NSIG). See [cross-ref to XSH sysconf()]. The value of {NSIG_MAX} shall be no greater than the number of signals that the sigset_t type (see [cross-ref to ]) is capable of representing, ignoring any restrictions imposed by sigfillset() or sigaddset().

But it hasn't made it to POSIX yet (most probably it'll a part of the POSIX version - issue 8).

> 2. Will it really work to set the function f as handler given that it takes a parameter? Shouldn't it not have any parameters?

The parameter that the signal handling function takes doesn't matter when you are *setting* a signal disposition. It takes the signal number but that doesn't prevent you from using it as a handler for multiple signals.

But there are special cases you need to handle. Certain signals that can't caught or ignored (`SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`). There are other signals (`SIGFPE`, `SIGILL` and `SIGSEGV`) for which, while allowed to caught, the signal handler can't return to its caller (i.e. you need exit from the signal handler).

Answer (score 5):

I would personally instead iterate over a static list of signal numbers, and use preprocessor directives to detect which ones are supported (at compile time). For example:

```
#include <signal.h>

static const all_signals[] = {
#ifdef SIGHUP
    SIGHUP,  /* POSIX.1 */
#endif
#ifdef SIGQUIT
    SIGQUIT, /* POSIX.1 */
#endif
#ifdef SIGTRAP
    SIGTRAP, /* POSIX.1 */
#endif
#ifdef SIGIO
    SIGIO,   /* BSD/Linux */
#endif

/*
 * Other signal names omitted for brevity
*/

/* C89/C99/C11 standard signals: */
    SIGABRT,
    SIGFPE,
    SIGILL,
    SIGINT,
    SIGSEGV,
/* SIGTERM (C89/C99/C11) is also the terminating signal number */
    SIGTERM
};
```

with `SIGTERM` being the last entry in the array for which a signal handler is installed:

```
    struct sigaction  act;
    int               i = 0;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = your_signal_handler;
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    do {
        if (sigaction(all_signals[i], &act, NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install signal %d handler: %s.\n", all_signals[i], strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } while (all_signals[i++] != SIGTERM);
```

This way your code does not require POSIX etc. support to work, but does support POSIX signals if available at compile time.

You can check the Wikipedia [Unix signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) article and [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for known signal names.

You can also install the signal handler for POSIX realtime signals using

```
#if SIGRTMAX-0 > SIGRTMIN-0
    for (i = SIGRTMIN; i <= SIGRTMAX; i++)
        if (sigaction(i, &act, NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install realtime signal %d handler: %s.\n", i, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. How can a get all the possible signals? Is there a function for this? Can I iterate through them in some way?

Seems like there isn't a standardized list you can iterate, but we actually don't need such a list for your task. Signal numbers are always positive and at most `SIGRTMAX`. In between `1` and `SIGRTMAX` there might be some numbers that do not correspond to any signal, but you can still try to set a handler for these. From the [posix specification of `sigaction(sig, ...)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/sigaction.html) (emphasis mine):

> RETURN VALUE
> Upon successful completion, `sigaction()` shall return `0`; otherwise, `-1` shall be returned, `errno` shall be set to indicate the error, and **no new signal-catching function shall be installed**.
>
> ERRORS
> The `sigaction()` function shall fail if:
> [EINVAL]
> The `sig` argument is not a valid signal number or an attempt is made to catch a signal that cannot be caught or ignore a signal that cannot be ignored.

So it is perfectly fine to call `sigaction(123, ...)` where `123` is *not* a signal.

#### 2. Will it really work to set the function f as handler given that it takes a parameter? Shouldn't it not have any parameters?

Why do you think it should have no parameters?
Again, from the [posix specification of `sigaction()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/sigaction.html):

> | Member Type | Member Name | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `void(*) (int)` | `sa_handler` | Pointer to a signal-catching function |

The signal handler is supposed to have an `int` parameter, just like your function `f` has, so there is no problem.

#### Putting everything together

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct sigaction siga;

void f(int sig) {
    printf("Caught signal %d\n", sig);
}

// sets f as handler to all the possible signals.
void myfunct(void(*f)(int sig)) {
    siga.sa_handler = f;
    for (int sig = 1; sig <= SIGRTMAX; ++sig) {
        // this might return -1 and set errno, but we don't care
        sigaction(sig, &siga, NULL);
    }
}

int main() {
    myfunct(f);
    pause(); // wait for signal
    return 0;
}
```